# Why Microsoft abandoned Notification Services in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I invested quite a bit of time toying  with NS introduced in SQL 2005 and found it to be excellent feature..

However , I hear MS has abandoned NS in 2008; Why ? and with what they are replacing it if any at all..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Deeply buried inside the readme file
>   for the July CTP of Katmai, Microsoft
>   quietly announced a departure from the
>   normal feature depreciation plan. The
>   readme stated that Notifications
>   Services would no longer be included
>   in the product. The following is an
>   excerpt from that ReadMe file.
>
> "SQL Server Notification Services will
>   not be included as a component of SQL
>   Server 2008, but will continue to be
>   supported as part of the SQL Server
>   2005 product support life-cycle.
>   Moving forward, **support for key
>   notification scenarios will be
>   incorporated into SQL Server Reporting
>   Services**. Existing Reporting Services
>   functionality, such as data driven
>   subscriptions, addresses some of the
>   notification requirements. Features to
>   support additional notification
>   scenarios may be expected in future
>   releases."

[Ref](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/08/22/60298.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Mitch already said, the official replacement for NS is RS. But I suggest you have a look at [StreamInsight](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2-complex-event.aspx).